# How to convert DateTimeOffset ToString("o") offset set to be 00

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

**DateTimeOffset.Now** = `{2/22/2018 10:32:50 AM -06:00}` been converted to 
**xmlformatTime** = `"2018-02-22T10:33:18.2670639-06:00"`, , in the format need to remove and expected **o/p** as `2018-02-22T10:33:18.00-06:00`.

18.2670639 needs to change as 18.00

```
DateTimeOffset PassDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
int minutes = PassDate.Minute;
int seconds = PassDate.Second;
var  offset = PassDate.Offset;
var xmlformatTime = PassDate.ToString("o");
Console.WriteLine(xmlformatTime)
```

[image]

when tried with below option.

```
var xmlformatTime = PassDate.ToString("'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.00'K");
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip):

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier corresponds to the `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffzzz"` custom format string for DateTimeOffset values

So use

```
var xmlformatTime = PassDate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.00'zzz");
```

instead to change the milliseconds to zeros.

Comment: @D stanley i have tried your option ,exception in below line `System.FormatException: 'Cannot find a matching quote character for the character '''.'`attached a screenshot above

Comment: @MohamedSahir Sorry I missed that it was a `DateTimeOffset` and had a bug in my copy-paste. bati06 has fixed both.

Comment: @D stanley thank you made my day!!!!